Kafka Connect logging - json template
I need to use a JSon template for logs, so logStash can receive multiline strings and traces as a single message.
Kafka Connect is on reload - IIUC this is the same config interface as log4j 1: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/logging.html
What's the thinnest way to solve this?
I don't want to write my own template to handle all the gnarly escaping- surely this is solved already.
My current bet is to use this 10 year old plugin:
https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout
Good chance I'm doing it wrong, and many many people are using Kafka Connect with logstash and have solved this already.   Should I use a bridge to send into a different logging implementation instead of log4j 1?
Thanks!
